# What information can we access from current logged in user MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

What information can we gather from a current logged in user to our application?

Does the server hold any information regarding Computer name on the network or OS used or any other information like that?

Thanks

**Edit** I will need to basically derive a table as below:

```
Username     Computer-Network Name    OS      Last Logged in date
  Craig           craig-pc            WIN7          today
```

I know I can get the last logged in date etc but not the other information, the reason for this is the system is being migrated from desktop to the web

Comment: I think you will get the User details from Server. (domainname\username, user group etc). Requested Browser, UserAgent et c may helps you to identify the OS,browser name etc. Please provide your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What information can we gather from a current logged in user to our application?

The username.

> Does the server hold any information regarding Computer name on the
>   network or OS used or any other information like that?

No. But you could of course retrieve this information additionally by looking at the `Request.UserHostAddress` property for example to retrieve the IP address. This could be done per request basis.

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
Request.Browser.Platform
```

To retrieve the platform/OS the user is on and the version via

```
Request.UserAgent
```

And you can use this to retrieve the computer name:

```
var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.UserHostAddress);
string hostName = host.HostName; //Computer name
```

Comment: Thanks @DGibbs, OK so all the information we could possible obtain is in the Request headers?

Comment: Is there a way to do this for every Logged in user or per request basis?

Comment: In the interest of learning, could the downvoter explain what's wrong with this answer?

Comment: Question asks for every user logged in and not per request only

Comment: No it doesn't... __"What information can we gather from a current logged in user to our application?"__ This code could be used to return the information you want for every user logged in, depending on how you use it... __"and not per request only"__ You explicitly asked for that in a comment above __"Is there a way to do this for every Logged in user or per request basis?"__. You need to clearly define your requirements if you want further help.